# Type Error: 'undefined' is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to create a date picker with an HTML form. In my HTML header I have

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            jQuery('#from').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            });
            jQuery('#to').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            });
</script>
```

My form is:

```
<form action="rural_report.php" method="post">
            Date From: <input type='text' id='from' name='from'/><br/>
            Date To: <input type='text' id='to' name='to'/><br/>
            <input type='submit' value='Get Rural Call Report'/>
</form>
```

I have tried wrapping the script in a document.ready function like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('#from').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            });
            jQuery('#to').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            });
});
```

I have also tried using a "$" instead of "jQuery". I have tried putting the script block in the HTML head with and without the document.ready bit, in the body before the form with the document.ready bit and at the very end of the body with and without the document.ready bit.

I am using Safari. The error I am getting is

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jQuery('#from').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            })')
```

When I type in a $ or the word jQuery at the bottom of the debug tool, I get the statement

```
function (a, b) {return new n.fn.init(a,b);}
```

When I click on the text box, it gets a blue glow around it, but the calendar does not show up.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you must also include [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) when you want to use the datepicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to add jQuery UI as well, the datepicker is not available in the core jQuery files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#from').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        });
        $('#to').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        });
    });
</script>
```